# How can I emulate this button without using background image?

Tags: css

I'd like to emulate the following button in CSS without using an image for the background arrow.  I'm still in the learning process, so I'm a bit perplexed by how I can accomplish this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xklyD

Comment: The answer is simple: You can't.

Comment: @MightyPork, he can, with a lot of CSS work.

Comment: @MightyPork of course you can...

Comment: Well then, post an answer, I want to learn something new :P

Comment: You really can with pure CSS but what have you tried?? just with google http://www.css3shapes.com/ make your try and come here with an specific question

Comment: You can make a pair of darker CSS triangles in the corners using `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: Danko and SLaks, Ok I see where you guys are going with this.  I think I can figure it out now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your button element add 2 divs, the second being a triangle.

```
<button>
  <div class="text">Login</div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</button>
```

And use [this triangle css by Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). Make the 2 inner divs light blue, and give the button a dark blue background color.